# What's the purpose of Kotlin's intrinsic `areEqual` method?

Tags: kotlin, compiler-construction, language-design

Let's say I have a

```
data class Eq(x: Int?)
```

This will generate an `equals` method that looks something like this

```
public boolean equals(Object other){
    if(this == other) return true;
    if(!(other instanceof Eq)) return false;
    Eq otherEq = (Eq) other;
    return Intrinsics.areEqual(this.x, otherEq.x);
}
```

Where intrinsic

```
public static boolean areEqual(Object first, Object second){
    return first == null ? second == null : first.equals(second);
}
```

And I don't quite understand the motivation behind that.

What's the benefit in keeping the static invocation as opposed to inlining its implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keeping the intrinsic as a static method rather than inlining it at each use site has a few advantages:

- It does not blow up the resulting binaries. For most intrinsics, a method call is smaller in the bytecode than the inlined body would be. Inlining the intrinsic would therefore lead to growth of the resulting binaries size.
- The intrinsic implementation is kept under control in the language evolution process and is consistent across all call sites. As the intrinsic is kept as a method, a newer runtime library might provide a better implementation that will be applied to all call sites at once, as opposed to different binaries having different versions inlined.

As for inlining at compilation time for the sake of performance, in the JVM world, this is usually not feasible. The JVM bytecode is quite a high-level abstraction (a stack machine code, which is far from real hardware), and the JVM itself is good at inlining method calls during JIT-compilation, so the compilers usually don't run micro-optimizations and rely on the optimizations built into the JVM implementations.

Answer (score 1):

By keeping `Intrinsics.areEqual` as a separate function, you can still use it when you override `equals`.

Kotlin itself uses this in several places, e.g. in [PropertyReference.java](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/deb416484c5128a6f4bc76c39a3d9878b38cec8c/libraries/stdlib/jvm/runtime/kotlin/jvm/internal/PropertyReference.java)